# Azure SQL Database Billing on new service tiers (Basic,Standard,and Premium)

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, billing

As per title, I am confused with the new service tiers for azure SQL.

I understand that the current pricing for Web and Business is actually calculated based on the actual size stored on the server. But I am confused with the new service tiers, which is basic,standard and premium.

As from here, http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/#basic-standard-and-premium, they are saying, for example, a STANDARD tier database will cost me ~$20(preview price with 50% discount).

My question is, if I create two database with STANDARD tier(which can support up to 250GB), but with 5GB each, will it be billed as $20/DB(which will cost me $40) or $20 for two DB(since its not exceeding the limit of 250GB)? ps. I do used the pricing calculator that provided here, http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=data-management. but it just sound weird and ridiculous to me if I created a database with only 1-2gb but paying $20(which may be increased to $40) for each DB. I just need some clarification. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will pay 2 x $20 so $40 (preview price). It is largely no longer based on database size but other performance metrics. For low usage databases you could use the basic tier which is cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Cheaper and much slower. Azure SQL Database just became not useful for small databases that want high performance.

Comment: True, with the new tier available. I just feel I am being abandon as a 'not so heavy' user. Would consider self host or move to another provider.